# Erlang re and lists index base difference

Tags: regex, list, erlang

Just ran into this odd case, violating the Principle of Least Astonishment (as subjective as it might be).

When using re:run/2, I obtain tuples for captured groups. Next line, I'm extracting the substrings captured.
To my great surprise, the indexing of the characters is inconsistent between these two operations. re:run/2's CaptureData is 0-based, while lists:sublist/3 is 1-based:

```
172> Line = "8#123abc#".                  
"8#123abc#"
173> re:run(Line,"^(\\d+)#(.+#$)").
{match,[{0,9},{0,1},{2,7}]}
174> lists:sublist(Line,0,1).
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:nthtail(-1,"8#123abc#") (lists.erl, line 180)
     in function  lists:sublist/3 (lists.erl, line 345)
175> lists:sublist(Line,1,1).
"8"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to explain this surprising inconsistency? Sorry if this question is more about philosophy that problem-solving (the solution here is obvious enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the OTP libraries have quite a number of API inconsistencies, for historical reasons. Erlang/OTP takes backward compatibility very seriously, which unfortunately also means that bad API-s take very-very lon time to fix. If ever.

Some examples for similar inconsistencies:

- The name of the `string` and `queue` modules are singular nouns vs. the plural nouns used for `lists` or `maps`.
- The `string` module uses 1-based indexing, while `binary` uses 0-based.
- If you want to look up a value from a `dict` or `map`, you pass the key as the first argument and the collection as the second. For `ets` tables the order of arguments is the opposite.

Elixir made a great effort for creating consistent API-s in their standard libraries by the way.

Regarding this particular problem you found: I guess the `string` module uses 1-based indexing because strings are actually lists of code points, and the `lists` module is using 1-based indexing too (but I don't know why). As for `re`, it probably uses 0-based indexing because binaries use that and I *think* regex matching is done on binaries, not lists (the regex code is based on `libpcre`, a C project, so it makes more sense to use binaries and 0-based indexing here).